# android изменение громкости "профиль звука"

Tags: java, android

Когда я пользуюсь некоторыми приложениями, где играет музыка или видео,  то когда хочу изменить громкость хард кнопками - вместо громкости видео и звука меняется громкость будильника или громкость звонка. И тогда нужно нажимать на кнопку настроек и менять именно громкость устройства. Это жутко бесит.

В моем приложение точно так же. Я могу как то программно повлиять на какой профиль звука будут влиять хард кнопки?

на всякий случай скрин, что бы было ясно о чем я:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод setVolumeControlStream() используется для прямого доступа к клавишам регулировки громкости для звукового потока, который вы укажете. Выяснив, какой аудио поток будет использовать приложение, вы должны установить его в качестве выходного звукового потока. Обычно его вызывают в методе onCreate().

setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
С этого момента нажатия клавиш регулировки громкости на устройстве влияют на указанный звуковой поток, когда ваша активность или фрагмент являются видимым.

Источник: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/audiomanager.php

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int action = event.getAction();
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
                }
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, 0);
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```